# ggplot2 fills holes in polygons

Tags: r, ggplot2, donut-polygons

I have a shapefile composed of polygons (sample [here](https://spaces.hightail.com/space/LD9SO)), many of which have holes in them. I cleaned the polygon layer in GRASS. After cleaning, QGIS's 'Check Geometry Validity' tool returned no errors. I then loaded the shapefile to R as follows:

```
polys <- readOGR(dsn=path.expand("U:/FandR"), layer="polygon")
polysCRS<- spTransform(polygons, CRS("+init=epsg:32717"))
polysCRS@data$id=rownames(polysCRS@data)
polysCRS.points = fortify(polysCRS, region="id")
polysCRS.df = join(polynsCRS.points, polysCRS@data, by="id")
```

Unfortunately, upon plotting, I can see that the holes in the polygons are filled.

```
#plot the polygons!
ggplot(polysCRS.df)+
  aes(long,lat,group=group)+
  geom_polygon(fill="#006600")+
  geom_path(color="white") +
  coord_equal()
```

Here is an image of a portion of my polygon plot, zoomed in to see the worst portion of the plot.

How can I correct this mistake in my loaded SpatialPolygonsDataFrame?

[image: Filled holes in polygon]

Comment: It is not readOGR but a ggplot2::geom_polygon problem. It can only do one hole per poly, and only sleight of hand anyway. Search "geom_holygon" for a workaround, or use spplot or just plot in sp (that use pathGrob and polypath)

Comment: Thanks, @mdsumner! I edited the title and tag to refer to ggplot2. I'm looking into these options now.

Comment: You could fake the holes by telling aes that group is "piece" and setting all hole fill to white

Comment: @mdsumner Thanks for your suggestions! geom_holgon worked for me just beautifully! Although 'faking the holes' would have served adequately for my purposes, I could not make the 'group=piece' modification. I had had to set group=group to prevent polygon tearing, as in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465040/ggplot2-facet-plot-of-shapefile-polygons-produces-strange-lines ; and when I modified to 'piece' those interrupting lines were reintroduced.

Comment: Oh, the pieces must not be unique in fortify, like in raster::geom (Good catch).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can now use package sf and the development version of ggplot2 (e.g. devtools::install_github('tidyverse/ggplot2')).

```
# load libraries
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

# read the sample data you provided (I converted to geopackage)
polys <- st_read('poly-hole.gpkg') 

# plot
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = polys, fill="#006600", color="white")
```

[image]