# Only a part of the shapefile plotted with ggplot2 in R

Tags: shapefile, r, mapping, ggplot2, donut-polygons

I would like to plot shapefiles from the EUFORGEN website (http://www.euforgen.org/) in R (European beech and Scots pine). At first I had problems, because they are files with holes. I was able to solve this problem for beech using [sebdalgarno](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201174/ggplot2-fills-holes-in-polygons)’s hint.

For pine it is a bit more difficult, because with the same method, suddenly only single fragments (isolated population) are displayed but not the core population (see picture).

I could imagine that I could "adjust" something when reading in the file, so that the whole layer is displayed.

Any ideas?

**Edit** (referring to the comment from @Spacedman)

I'm sorry, but I don't know how to read a shape-file via r-script from the internet. If someone knows how to do that, I can change that with pleasure. Therefore here again the link to the cloud

[Cloud_Beech(Fagus sylvatica) and Pine(Pinus sylvestris)](https://owncloud.gwdg.de/index.php/s/08PjFVg0hjhioJl)

or to the zip-file from the Webpage
[EUFORGEN.org](https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/hr5h2hcgg4/14)

Here is the map as it is almost correct. The darker small areas (e.g., in Norway and Sweden) are holes in the polygon, but are not displayed correctly with `geom_polygon()`.

```
library("rnaturalearth")
library("rgdal")
library("ggplot2")


gg_world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sp")  # world map as sp class

Pinus <- readOGR("./chorological_maps_dataset/Pinus sylvestris/shapefiles/Pinus_sylvestris_plg_clip.shp")


ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(data = gg_world, mapping=aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), fill = "white", color = "grey50")+
  # Species shape file
  geom_polygon(data = Pinus, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), colour = "black", fill = "darkblue", alpha = 0.2)+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-15, 40), ylim=c(35, 75), default = F)+
  # Layout
  theme_bw()+
  # axes
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), name = "Longitude (°E)")+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), name = "Latitude (°N)")
```

[image: Pine distribution with geom_polygon()]

So I continued with [sebdalgarno](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201174/ggplot2-fills-holes-in-polygons)'s suggestion and used `geom_sf()` and as also above, with the hint from [Spacedman](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/865/spacedman) to use a world map in sf format. I used `ne_countries` from the `rnaturalearth` packages

```
gg_world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
Pinus_st <- st_read("./chorological_maps_dataset/Pinus sylvestris/shapefiles/Pinus_sylvestris_plg_clip.shp")


ggplot() + 
 
  
  geom_sf(data = Pinus_st, colour = NA, fill = "darkblue", alpha = 0.5)+
  #geom_sf(data = Fagus_st, colour = NA, fill = "red", alpha = 0.5)+
  geom_sf(data = gg_world, fill = NA, color = "grey50")+
  
  coord_sf(xlim=c(-15, 40), ylim=c(35, 75), expand = F)+
  
  # Layout
  theme_bw()+
  
  # axes
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), name = "Longitude (°E)")+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), name = "Latitude (°N)")
```

and get this

[image: only single polygones]

A new step-by-step build of the code then showed that the map section boundary was causing the error. As was also the case here [Link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/403851/is-there-a-way-to-zoom-in-on-a-mapped-polygon-spatialpolygonsdataframe-in-r). If one takes out the alpha command, it works.

```
gg_world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
Pinus_st <- st_read("./chorological_maps_dataset/Pinus sylvestris/shapefiles/Pinus_sylvestris_plg_clip.shp")


ggplot() + 
 
  
  geom_sf(data = Pinus_st, colour = NA, fill = "darkblue")+
  geom_sf(data = gg_world, fill = NA, color = "grey50")+
  coord_sf(xlim=c(-15, 40), ylim=c(35, 75), expand = F)+
  # Layout
  theme_bw()+
  # axes
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), name = "Longitude (°E)")+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), name = "Latitude (°N)")
```

[image: Zoom in distribution pine]

Comment: Can you show us what you expect the map to look like? Have you tried plotting your data with a simple base "plot" call to see if its a problem with ggplot's maps or with the data? Can you tell us exactly which of the shapefiles in the linked downloads you are working with in order for us to replicate your workflow? Can you explain where `getMap` comes from because its not in your library list? Can you give `Pinus_st <- st_read()` an argument so it actually runs? Please edit your question down to a minimal example that runs and illustrates the problem.

Comment: Now `gg_world` appears in your code but its not created anywhere. Also, two of your shapefile links need an OwnCloud password, and the other is to just the `.shp` file, which won't work properly without the .shx, .prj and .dbf. All you need to say is "Download and unzip chorological_maps_dataset_20211007.zip (Mb) from [link]" and then use paths relative to that, eg `Pinus = st_read("./chorological_maps_dataset/Pinus sylvestris/shapefiles/Pinus_sylvestris_plg_clip.shp")`

Comment: It looks like either the shapefile or ggplot's geom_polygon is broken. I'd switch to `sf` spatial objects and then use `tmap` for mapping, or if you want to stick with ggplot, then use `geom_sf` - but you'll probably have to find a `sf` country outline basemap because the one from `rworldmap` is `sp` class... that could be converted.. except it has some unclosed polygon errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is buggy somewhere. Here's how I'd map that shapefile with `tmap`:

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)

data(World)

Pinus = st_read("./chorological_maps_dataset/Pinus sylvestris/shapefiles/Pinus_sylvestris_plg_clip.shp")

xlim=c(-15, 40)
ylim=c(35, 75)


map = tm_shape(World, bbox=bb(xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)) +
    tm_graticules() + 
    tm_polygons("white") +
    tm_shape(Pinus) + tm_polygons("darkblue", alpha=0.2) 

print(map) # or just "map" if interactive
```

Adjust colours, labels etc as per requirements, but this is close enough:

[image]

I see the holes in Scandinavia which I guess were the real problems.

Or with `ggplot`, using the same `Pinus` read as before, as an `sf` object:

```
ggplot() + geom_sf(data=World) + geom_sf(data = Pinus, fill="darkblue", alpha=0.2) +
    coord_sf(xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
```

I prefer `tmap` because its easy to change the mode and make an interactive browser map, but I give the `ggplot` map as well anyway.

[image]

And for completion here's the base graphics version:

```
plot(st_geometry(World), xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
plot(Pinus, add=TRUE, col="#00008040")
```

[image]

Comment: I like your solution with tmap. Thanks for your help!